# bitbucket create pull request ignoring 1 commit

Tags: bitbucket

I want to create a pull request in bitbucket that has 2 different commits, but I want to ignore 1 commit and make the pull request only from the other one

[image]

Comment: you can create new branch and use cherry-pick for this commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone your repository and then checkout the commit you are interested in.

```
git clone your_repository

git checkout abc
```

This will create a copy of the state you are interested in in your HEAD.